# Oracle SQL query to return rows that matches a column value having not a digit

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am using the following Oracle SQL query to list down the rows for a column that has values other than digits.

```
select * from XXX_ACCOUNTS_20110309 p 
  where regexp_like (bar_status,'[[^:digit:]]+');
```

The above query doesnt return any rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
where bar_status like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (I can't test it)

```
select * from XXX_ACCOUNTS_20110309 p 
where not regexp_like (bar_status,'[[:digit:]]+');
```

or

```
select * from XXX_ACCOUNTS_20110309 p 
where not regexp_like (bar_status,'^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Comment: i want anythin other than a number.

Comment: @Suresh added the NOT keywords